# How to hide rows in Excel based on values in two columns

Tags: vba, excel

First post here and i am very new to the world of Excel-VBA.

I am trying to automate some reports and have run into a little snag. i am trying to hide rows on an excel worksheet based on the value of cells in 2 seprate columns. i have given given an example below. (The real Document can contain up to 50 names at one given time and pretty much any date.)

For this example i would need to hide all rows that do not have the value JIM in column A and have a greater date than todays date in column B. (04/05/2014)

```
A       B
JIM     04/05/2014
JIM     04/05/2014
BOB     05/05/2014
BOB     04/05/2014
TED     07/05/2014
TED     04/05/2014
BOB     09/05/2014
JIM     04/05/2014
JIM     11/05/2014
TED     12/05/2014
```

I am using the below code at the minute but ran into some issues when adding a second argument.

```
Sub Delete_Name_Date()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:F15")
If cell.Value = "JIM" Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else: cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If
Next


End Sub
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Delete_Name_Date()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A15")
        With cell
            .EntireRow.Hidden = _
                (.Value <> "JIM" And CDate(.Offset(, 1).Value) > Date)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

also for reliability I suggest you to use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A15")` instead `Range("A1:A15")`

Comment: Hey Simoco,

Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.

The code works fine on the example however i seem to be getting the following error when trying to use it in my document :(

Run-ime Error '13'

Type Mismatch

any idea why this could be? the data in the document is the same as the example provided.

Cheers Adam

Comment: two reasons `1)` your range `Range("A1:B15")` contains errors like `#N/A` `#DIV/0` and etc.. `2)` your dates stored with wrong date format and `CDate(.Offset(, 1).Value)` causes the error. Try to change  `CDate(.Offset(, 1).Value)` to `DateValue(.Offset(, 1).Text)`

Comment: Hey Simoco came back to this today and you were right the range contained errors amended and everything is working fine. You’re a life saver.  Thanks again